# install a minimal 64bit Ubuntu 12.04 server virtual machine to use alongside a 32bit Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, virtualbox, vmware, virtualization

I would like to install a minimal 64bit Ubuntu 12.04 server virtual machine to basically be able to use a terminal to run 64bit code alongside my 32bit Ubuntu 12.04 gnome session on my 64bit virt-enabled laptop. Where can I find the installation instructions for the best option to achieve my goal? VirtualBox? VMWare? Something else?

Comment: Use virtualbox cause its the best virtualization software in the market and Open-source.

Comment: well you could just install vmware and install using thst

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I find the installation instructions for the best option to achieve my goal?

### VMWare Player (or Workstation)

From personal experience, I can tell you that VMWare Player will almost certainly work for you, given that you have this scenario:

- Intel/AMD 64-bit Processor with Virtualization (VT) extensions
- 32-bit Linux Host
- 64-bit Linux Guest

Try VMWare Player, and it will let you know what the problem is if it can't do what you want. (I couldn't find official instructions with a quick Google Search.

### VirtualBox

Virtualbox also has a similar feature since version 2.1, with similar requirements. From [Chapter 3](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html) of the Virtualbox manual:

> - VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit host operating systems, provided that the following conditions are met:
>
>   1. You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see the section called “Hardware vs. software virtualization”).
>   2. You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.
>   3. If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon explicit request.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nicely put VirtualBox, in other words: You can do it, but you shouldn't. I think that applies for all virtualization solutions on the market.